# Will Keras Regularizer l1_l2 work as either L1 or L2 when any of those is set to zero?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

Just like [given in the ElasticNet documentation of Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html) as:

> The ElasticNet mixing parameter, with 0 <= l1_ratio <= 1.

> **For l1_ratio = 0 the penalty is an L2 penalty.**

> **For l1_ratio = 1 the penalty is an L1 penalty.**

> For 0 < l1_ratio < 1, the penalty is a combination of L1 and L2.

Similarly there is:

```
regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4)
regularizers.l1(1e-5)
regularizers.l2(1e-4)
```

I would like to know if used with `Dense` layer, will below 2 regularizations behave exactly the same?

`regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0, l2=1e-4)`

`regularizers.l2(1e-4)`?